# Heroku: Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, crash, rails-activestorage

My app deploys to Heroku but crashes every time. I don't know why. I have set up Carrierwave, fog, and aws for an app in production on Heroku before just fine. Tried to follow the same steps and I am getting an h10 error code. In the rails console it specifically says:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.1/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:76:in
>   `block (2 levels) in ': Couldn't find Active Storage
>   configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)

```
storage.yml 

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>


# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: "S3_KEY"
  secret_access_key: "S3_SECRET"
  region: "us-east-1"
  bucket: "books4reviews"
```

production.rb

```
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'

config.fog_credentials = {
  provider: 'AWS',
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['S3_KEY'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],
  region: 'us-east-1'
}
config.fog_directory  = 'books4reviews'
config.fog_public = false
config.storage = :fog
end
```

puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

    port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

   environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

  plugin :tmp_restart
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  process resize_to_fit: [500,500]

  version :small do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
  end

  version :medium do

      # change the word 'fit' to 'fill'
      process resize_to_fill: [400,600]
  end

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [1000,1000]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [50, 50]
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

I've set my env variables for the aws credentials in my heroku config variables from the terminal. Can you tell me why I'm getting this active storage error? Thanks

Answer (score 57):

I had this same issue when deploying a recently upgraded Rails app. The application was upgraded from **Rails 5** to **Rails 6**. However, when I try deploying to **Heroku**, I got the error below:

```
2021-02-12T17:32:33.404828+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: RuntimeError: Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml
2021-02-12T17:32:33.404874+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/puma)
2021-02-12T17:32:33.404958+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I checked the `config` directory of my application and realized that it had no `config/storage.yml` file. All I had to do was to create the file, and copy the vanilla template that comes with **Rails 6** applications into the file:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the Azure Storage secret (as azure_storage:storage_access_key)
# microsoft:
#   service: AzureStorage
#   storage_account_name: your_account_name
#   storage_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:azure_storage, :storage_access_key) %>
#   container: your_container_name

# mirror:
#   service: Mirror
#   primary: local
#   mirrors: [ amazon, google, microsoft ]
```

This time when I deployed everything worked fine.

**Note**: You can modify the file content based on your storage configurations

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: This saved me. Thank you! :)

Comment: Exactly the same issue I had. Upgrading from Rails 5 to 6 then a `storage.yml` is needed even I don't actually use storage.

Answer (score 2):

This may not fix your issue, but I had ".yaml" instead of ".yml" because I had to manually create the file "/config/storage.yml" manually and made a typo.

Hope this helps someone, as I couldn't find many results on this error.

FYI, I think the generator didn't create the storage.yml file because I was on Rails 5.1, originally and then upgraded to 5.2

Comment: I fixed this issue but forgot to close out the question. Can’t remember what I did it was so long ago lol.